# $this->var or $var

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I just started using OOP / CodeIgniter. I want to get assign the form input to variables. I wonder which one I should use `$this -> var` or  `$var` and how they differ from each other? Thanks.

For example

```
$agree = $this -> input -> post( 'agree' );
```

OR

```
$this -> agree = $this -> input -> post( 'agree' );
```

Both will work fine like:

```
if ($agree) { }
```

OR

```
if ($this -> agree){ }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of scope

```
<?php
    class Example extends CI_Controller
    {
        private $agree1;

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $agree2 = $this->input->post( 'agree' );
            $this->agree1 = $this->input->post( 'agree' );

            // within this context both are accessable
            // these will print the same
            var_dump($agree2);
            var_dump($this->agree1);

            // call the helper function
            $this->helper();
        }

        private function helper()
        {
            // within this context $agree2 is not defined
            // these will NOT print the same. Only the 2nd will print the content of the post
            var_dump($agree2);
            var_dump($this->agree1);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really a matter of preference when it comes to extra local variables. As general guidance, I would use `$var` if the variable is only pertinent to the method, and `$this->var` if it makes sense for other methods to use this variable too.

If you are just collecting the input and handling it in that method, I would just use a local variable. Class members are normally used for things relevant to the class/object, for example a class representing a vehicle might have a `$number_of_wheels` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're talking about what to use inside a controller/action pair?

`$this->var` actually refers to a property of your controller class named `var`.

`$var` means that it's a locally (function) scoped variable

If you do not specifically want to access a class property, don't use `$this`. Just use `$var` and have it accessible only within the scope of the function.

If you are actually referring to a class property and you want this property to be acessible by all methods in your class, make sure you declare it in your class definition on top.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `$this->var` then you are referring to a **class variable**. If you are assigning it to just `$var` then you are referring to a **local variable**. I am gussing you need to make use of the following if you don't need the form values to be available to other methods:

`$agree = $this->input->post('agree');`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you want to set a local variable or an object variable.

You should have your object variable declared at the beginning of the class (e.g. `private $var`) - they are accessible from different methods across the class.

Local variable is accessible only in the scope of current method.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->agree)` if you're going to use it in other functions of the class, `$agree` if using it within the current scope, meaning inside the function making it a local variable only.

Answer (score -2):

I think only `$this->agree` works, however, I have not tested this.

Ad@m